# Looking for US County elevation data

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, county

I'd like to explore the connection between altitude and suicide rates discussed in the 2011 paper, [Positive Association between Altitude and Suicide in 2584 U.S. Counties](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3114154/).

I can get some data for the suicide rates from the [CDC WISQARS](http://wisqars.cdc.gov:8080/cdcMapFramework/) site, though unfortunately they don't report raw data for small population counties.

I'm still looking for a data set providing elevation data for counties, such as the elevation of the county seats or a mean elevation for the whole county.

Comment: The USGS has NED, the [National Elevation Dataset](http://ned.usgs.gov/), but the granularity is much higher than county.  (and I'm not sure what you'd have to do to get county info back out of it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the Area Health Resource File ([AHRF](http://ahrf.hrsa.gov/download.htm))? It has elevation data and then some for this type of analysis.

Comment: Hadn't seen it. Wish it weren't 100MB of text to parse! But it looks workable though it's missing elevation for HI and AK and parts of VA.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to mash things a little but this is available for free and should be fairly easy to setup:

Download the [2014 National Gazetteer, County Dataset](http://www2.census.gov/geo/gazetteer/2014_Gazetteer/2014_Gaz_counties_national.zip), a tab delimited text file with 3200+ US counties, by state, ANSI code with Lat and Long.

Then, bang away at the [USGS National Elevation Dataset Query Service](http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/) for the elevation of a given lat/long.

The Query Service page has code for both HTTP Get and HTTP Post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some MISC resources to add to Kotebiya answer. Below is the USGS quick facts on elevations in the US. It has a list of the high/lowest for the largest 50 cities. Some other tables as well.

http://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/Elevations-Distances/elvadist.html

Maryland's GIS site has a list of high/low per county:

http://www.mgs.md.gov/geology/highest_and_lowest_elevations.html

This is a hiking site that also contains a lot of elevation data:

http://www.cohp.org/

Answer (score 3):

census has longitude and latitude here by county:
https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/centersofpop.html

elevation data is also here:
http://nationalmap.gov/elevation.html

I was thinking you might be able to link the two together.

Comment: Have you found a more accessible elevation data set that this 4GB disk request at http://www.usgs.gov/faq/categories/9865/5171?

Comment: You can try copying and pasting the long and lat here: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/elevation.html  The data is from Google which differs from NED though.  That should allow you to cross reference long/lat with elevation.

Answer (score 0):

[ZipCodes.com](http://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code-database.asp)

It's not free but for $39.95(USD) it might cover what you need.

Comment: If you're going to suggest sources that don't fall under 'open data' ... could you at least confirm if they meet the need?

Comment: Joe, you're right. I lost track of the point of the forum.

For the entire US: primary county, county code (FIPS and ANSI), county's average elevation, and about 25 other fields.

Answer (score 0):

I went to [this website](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/board-on-geographic-names/download-gnis-data) (USGS board on geographic names), downloaded each state's information and then filtered the rows with "county" in the place name. Each state's URL can be programatically manipulated easily.